# In Meteor, using an object (defined in one file) in another file without global scoping?

Tags: meteor

I've got a `prices.js` file with a `ShoppingCartContents` object that is defined in this file.

I'd like to access this `ShoppingCartContents` object inside my `helpers.js` file, where I will be using it to create a global helper.

I can easily do this by just setting `ShoppingCartContents` to global, but I don't want to do that. Is there a better way? According to the docs there's `package scope` and `file scope`. These two scopes don't seem granular enough to me (there's also a package export feature but I'm doing everything inside one package)

Things can only be scoped to:

- one and only one file
- the entire package

Shouldn't there be a `file export` feature maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you're working inside a package, make the variable global. That way you can access it in all your files, for your package.

If you want a truly global variable, you have to explicitly export it, so there's no problem in using globals.

Comment: Are you sure? I have global variables in my `prices.js` file (I name and declare them as empty hashes at the top of my .js file without using `var`) and I can access those variables without an issue directly from Chrome Developer Console when I'm testing the website, no matter what path I'm in. I never explicitly exported those variables as global, and they are most definitely in the global namespace.

Comment: Are you working in a package-context or app-context?

Comment: Just your standard app-context.

Comment: Okay, then you can't do the whole global-thing. Globals will be globals, in the app-context.
I am unsure as to if you can do `this.ShoppingCartContents` as you can in a package, or if this is effecively a global variable as well.

Comment: Damn. I've heard that people write their apps so that every part of the app is effectively a package. Gives more control over a lot more things compared to the app way of doing it. Is this something that I should consider doing for all future projects?

Comment: I write most of my actual app in the app-context, as I'm not worried much about global variables. I have only one global variable, ie. `App` which I extend, from other places in my app.

The stuff I can reuse in other projects, (Achievements, Themes, Form Controls, etc.) I put in packages, for the most part.